# Spark, optimally splitting a single RDD into two

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataset that I need to split into groups according to specific parameters.  I want the job to process as efficiently as possible.  I can envision two ways of doing so

**Option 1** - Create map from original RDD and filter

```
def customMapper(record):
    if passesSomeTest(record):
        return (1,record)
    else:
        return (0,record)

mappedRdd = rddIn.map(lambda x: customMapper(x))
rdd0 = mappedRdd.filter(lambda x: x[0]==0).cache()
rdd1 = mappedRdd.filter(lambda x: x[1]==1).cache()
```

**Option 2** - Filter original RDD directly

```
def customFilter(record):
    return passesSomeTest(record)

rdd0 = rddIn.filter(lambda x: customFilter(x)==False).cache()
rdd1 = rddIn.filter(customFilter).cache()
```

The fist method has to itterate over all the records of the original data set 3 times, where the second only has to do so twice, under normal circumstances, however, spark does some behind the scenes graph building, so I could imagine that they are effectively done in the same way.  My questions are:
a.) Is one method more efficient than the other, or does the spark graph building make them equivalent
b.) Is it possible to do this split in a single pass

Comment: I also found my self with a very similar problem, and didn't really find a solution. But what *actually* happens is not clear from this code, because spark has 'lazy evaluation' and is supposedly capable of executing only what it really needs to execute, and also of combining maps, filters and whatever can be done together. So possibly what you describe *may* happen in a single pass. Not familiar enough with the lazy evaluation mechanisms to tell, though. Actually I just noticed the .cache(). Maybe there's a way of only doing one .cache() and getting the full results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all let me tell you that I'm not a Spark expert; I've been using it quite a lot in the last few months, and I believe I now understand it, but I may be wrong.

So, answering your questions:

a.) they are equivalent, but not in the way you're seeing it; Spark will not optimize the graph if you are wondering, but the `customMapper` will still be executed twice in both cases; this is due to the fact that for spark, `rdd1` and `rdd2` are two completely different RDDs, and it will build the transformation graph bottom-up starting from the leafs; so Option 1 will translate to:

```
rdd0 = rddIn.map(lambda x: customMapper(x)).filter(lambda x: x[0]==0).cache()
rdd1 = rddIn.map(lambda x: customMapper(x)).filter(lambda x: x[0]==1).cache()
```

As you said, `customMapper` is executed twice (moreover, also `rddIn` will be read twice, which means that if it comes from a database, it may be even slower).

b.) there is a way, you just have to move `cache()` in the right place:

```
mappedRdd = rddIn.map(lambda x: customMapper(x)).cache()
rdd0 = mappedRdd.filter(lambda x: x[0]==0)
rdd1 = mappedRdd.filter(lambda x: x[0]==1)
```

By doing this, we are telling spark that it can store the partial results of `mappedRdd`; it will then use these partial results both for `rdd1` and `rdd2`. From the spark point of view this is equivalent to:

```
mappedRdd = rddIn.map(lambda x: customMapper(x)).saveAsObjectFile('..')
# forget about everything
rdd0 = sc.objectFile('..').filter(lambda x: x[0]==0)
rdd1 = sc.objectFile('..').filter(lambda x: x[0]==1)
```